# Wordpress API to authorize a user

Tags: wordpress

Is there some API in Wordpress to 'authorize' a user? Let's say I want to implement something like:

```
if (1 == 1) {
  user_authenticate('userXY');
}
```

The method user_authenticate would initialize the session and send the necessary cookies to the user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of built-in WordPress functions that you may find helpful for what you're trying to do. I'm guessing the most helpful would be the `wp_set_auth_cookie` function (See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/).

You may want to try something like:

```php
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
$user = get_user_by('login', $username);
$user_id = $user->ID;
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
wp_set_current_user($user_id);
```

or something to that effect.

Here are some other user/cookie/session functions available to you:

**In the *wp-includes/pluggable.php* file**

- `wp_validate_auth_cookie` - Validates authentication cookie.
- `wp_generate_auth_cookie` - Generates authentication cookie contents.
- `wp_parse_auth_cookie` - Parses a cookie into its components.
- `wp_set_auth_cookie` - Sets the authentication cookies based on user ID.
- `wp_clear_auth_cookie` - Removes all of the cookies associated with authentication.
- `wp_get_current_user` - Retrieve the current user object.
- `wp_set_current_user` - Changes the current user by ID or name.

**In the *wp-includes/user.php* file**

- `wp_get_session_token` - Retrieve the current session token from the logged_in cookie.
- `wp_get_all_sessions` - Retrieve a list of sessions for the current user.
- `wp_destroy_current_session` - Remove the current session token from the database.
- `wp_destroy_other_sessions` - Remove all but the current session token for the current user for the database.
- `wp_destroy_all_sessions` - Remove all session tokens for the current user from the database.

There is also a great plugin (only one file long) that does this sort of thing called **User Switching** (See: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/). You may also find some very helpful code from poking around that file.